# How do I make a modulino in Perl6?

Tags: system, raku, modulino

I want to make a [modulino (a file that can run as either a module or a script)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=396759) in Perl6.

The following code "processes" file names from the command line:

```
sub MAIN ( *@filenames )
{
    for @filenames -> $filename
    {
        say "Processing $filename";
    }
}
```

Saving this as `main.pm6` I can run it and it works:

```
perl6 main.pm6 hello.txt world.txt
Processing 'hello.txt'
Processing 'world.txt'
```

So, I want this to be a module so that I can add functions and make testing it easier. However, when I add a `module` declaration to it, it no longer outputs anything:

```
module main;
sub MAIN ( *@filenames )
{
    for @filenames -> $filename
    {
        say "Processing '$filename'";
    }
}
```

Which results in nothing output:

```
perl6 main.pm6 hello.txt world.txt
```

So, how can I build a modulino in Perl6?

I'm using Perl6 running on [MoarVM](http://www.moarvm.com) from the [January 2015 release of Rakudo Star](http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/).

### UPDATE:

When I try wrapping the module in braces:

```
module main
{
    sub process (@filenames) is export
    {
        for @filenames -> $filename
        {
            say "Processing '$filename'";
        }
    }
};

sub MAIN ( *@filenames )
{
    process(@filenames)
}
```

I also get errors:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling main.pm6
Undeclared routine:
    process used at line 14. Did you mean 'proceed'?
```

Comment: it should be enough to put it outside the module, ie `module main { ... }; sub MAIN { ... }`

Comment: @Christoph It didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion. Is this a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, but a consequence of lexical scoping. There are several ways to structure your code: Declare `process` outside the module, make it `our`-scoped and call is as `main::process` or export it and add an `import` statement to the body of your sub `MAIN`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `MAIN` sub needs to be declared outside the module, but it still must be able to see `process`.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, eg by not declaring a module at all

```
sub process(@filenames) {
    for @filenames -> $filename {
        say "Processing '$filename'";
    }
}

sub MAIN(*@filenames) {
    process(@filenames);
}
```

by making `process` our-scoped and calling it by its longname

```
module main {
    our sub process(@filenames) {
        for @filenames -> $filename {
            say "Processing '$filename'";
        }
    }
}

sub MAIN(*@filenames) {
    main::process(@filenames);
}
```

or by exporting `process` and importing it in the body of `MAIN`

```
module main {
    sub process(@filenames) is export {
        for @filenames -> $filename {
            say "Processing '$filename'";
        }
    }
}

sub MAIN(*@filenames) {
    import main;
    process(@filenames);
}
```

In my opinion the most appropriate option is to add `MAIN` to the module and import it into the script's mainline. This way, everything declared within the module is visible within `MAIN` without having to explicitly export everything:

```
module main {
    sub process(@filenames) {
        for @filenames -> $filename {
            say "Processing '$filename'";
        }
    }

    sub MAIN(*@filenames) is export(:MAIN) {
        process(@filenames);
    }
}

import main :MAIN;
```

Note that this does not export `MAIN` by default, ie users of your module will only get it if they provide the `:MAIN` tag.